# ImportError: Error loading object 'scrap.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': No module named scrap.middlewares

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I have a portia scrapy project at `~/portia/slyd/data/projects/scrap` setup to use `scrap.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware` in DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES, `RandomUserAgentMiddleware` is defined in `~/portia/slyd/data/projects/scrap/middlewares.py`.

After deploying the project, the resulting egg doesn't contain the `middlewares.py`, so I get this error:

```
ImportError: Error loading object 'scrap.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': No module named scrap.middlewares
```

How do I tell scrapyd-deploy to take the custom middlewares as well?

Edit:

My `settings.py` is this: http://pastebin.com/8gFU3YEw

I also tried manually including the `middlewares.py` in the generated egg, but it doesn't solve it, still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

They should be placed in settings.py file. The DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES variable should be declared containing a list of custom middleware to be used. Here an example that should cover your case:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrap.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 5,
}
```

More info can be found here in the [official scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html).